# Check constant is defined but empty?

Tags: php, constants

```
<?php
    define ('foo','');
if (defined('foo')){
    if (empty(foo)){
        echo "Notice: Foo Is Defined, But Does Not Carry A Value. Please Set It";
    }
}
```

If have this current script, I am running a set of checks on defined constants which the user needs to define in the configuration page.. The problem is, the config gets shipped out with nothing defined:

```
define ('foo','');
```

and when running the script, I first check that the necessary constants are correctly defined and do carry a value.

The problem is, that I can get if the value is defined, but I cannot correctly check if it's empty.

I know with empty expects a variable passed, if i pass my defined constants into a variable, doesn't it kinda defeat the point?

```
<?php
 define ('Foo','');
 $Foo = Foo;
 if (empty($Foo)){
  echo "Foo Is Empty"; 
}
?>
```

Whereas I might aswell setup:

```
$Foo = 'Value';
$OtherConstant = 'Another';
```

so how can I check whether my constant is carrying a value when that is defined?

Comment: `strlen(foo) != 0` perhaps? Although that would also catch boolean `false`, which you might not want.

Comment: The values that translate to the empty string are the empty string itself, `null` and boolean `false`. The check above will match those and only those.

Comment: Argh! I was commenting on a question you recently added ("Validate a Visa debit via PHP") but you deleted it whilst I was adding another comment. Please don't do this - if a question attracts downvotes, that's just the risk of posting here.

Comment: @halfer Sorry for doing this, after consideration after a post by the other user, which made perfect logical sense I decided to delete the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could simply do that:

```
if (defined('foo')) {
    echo 'defined';
    if (foo) {
        echo 'not empty';
    }
    else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
}
else {
    echo 'not defined';
}
```

If foo is an empty string the `if(foo)` conditional will evaluate false. There are subtle differences between `empty()` and converting to boolean. Please refer to the PHP manual for other cases. [Boolean conversion](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting), [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php)